# How can I configure Windows 10 to launch Explorer on CTRL+Win?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm aware of the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut, and I know about the shortcut setting in the property page, but it enforces the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> for all shortcuts.

Is there any way to configure Windows 10 to launch Explorer on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly  do that with auto hot key.
There is a way to open "My computer" folder by command prompt :

'start file:'

(without quote)

you will can make your shortcut whit that =)